"HTTP 400, Item type is invalid for creating a Reply." error while trying to create Draft Reply in Outlook using Graph API
I am trying to create a Draft reply using Microsoft Graph API but sometime getting "HTTP 400, Item type is invalid for creating a Reply." error message

I would start with checking the actual mailbox eg is it over quota, is it enabled can you create and item in the drafts outside of replying,  does it have a valid license. Probably check the actual item your replying to as well is it an email, event invite etc

We get this error for the messages which cant be replied. So in my case I tried to create a draft reply to the microsoft outlook notification mails for message that couldn't be delivered
